# Side menu text going long

Tags: html, css

Side menu text going long i want this text set in single line

[image]

"(Options:Cooking Option:Med,Spicy:MediumTopings:Chicken Lemon...."

I need this type of alignment.

Comment: post the code which you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

what you need here is `ellipsis`, check my code below it should work for you

```css
div{
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  some really long textsome really long textsome really long textsome really long textsome really long textsome really long textsome really long text
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: glad I could help, next time try to post code which you have tried so far :)

Comment: @KesavaiahMannela if my solution works for you, you can mark it as accepted by clicking tick icon